# How to change the way org-alert gives notifications

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I noticed that my org-alert and org-wild-notifier both only give notifications down in the bottom buffer which is quite small and hard to see unless I am looking for it. Though on the org-alert GitHub(linked below) they have a screenshot of a notification in the top right hand corner and I can't quite figure out how to set that up. So I was hoping someone on here might have the answer.

https://github.com/spegoraro/org-alert

EDIT:

@NickD helped lead me in the right direction with their answer. It lead me to this email chain(https://www.mail-archive.com/gnu-emacs-sources@gnu.org/msg03921.html) and to this repo(https://github.com/mplscorwin/erc-burnt-toast) which should support notifications through BurntToast on Winodws 10. That being said, the install/setup directions are a bit above my head so I reached out to the maintainer and asked for clarification. I will hopefully update when they respond.

Comment: See the [Configuration](https://github.com/spegoraro/org-alert#configuration) section of the `org-alert` README.

Comment: @NickD I tried all of them aside from the ones that are OSX specific and gntp and they all give notifications in the same location.

Comment: is `libnotify` installed on your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location and shape of the notification varies with how each Desktop Environment deals with notifications. Make sure that you satisfy the prerequisites:

- install the libnotify library: on my Fedora system, I do `sudo dnf install libnotify`. If you use Debian or a derivative, you will probably have to say `sudo apt-get install libnotify` and similarly for other distros.
- install both [org-alert](https://github.com/spegoraro/org-alert.git) and [alert](https://github.com/jwiegley/alert.git). You may also have to install any additional dependencies that these two packages require.
- You need something like this in your emacs initialization file:

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path "/PATH/TO/org-alert")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/PATH/TO/alert")

(require 'alert)

(setq alert-default-style 'libnotify)

(require 'org-alert)
```

Change the paths in the first two lines to ones appropriate for your setup.

Then evaluate `(org-alert-check)` and see the notifications. On my Gnome desktop environment, they appear (like all notifications) in the top center of the screen and they are white-on-dark-background, but I presume that can be changed (for every notification, not only for org-alerts) by customizing foreground/background colors; but that is a Gnome problem and far outside the scope of this SE site. If you are using Gnome, check this [answer from Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579225/is-there-any-way-i-can-customize-gnome-as-much-as-possible/579226#579226); I found that answer by searching for `[Gnome] notification`, i.e. the string "notification" under the tag "Gnome". If you use a different DE, try changing the tag appropriately, e.g. `[kde] notification`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am unfortunately using a Windows 10 system but this answer was very similar to what I had to do on there.

Comment: Can you add to your findings to the answer? That will make it more useful for Windows people. Although I'm not sure how much reputation you need to edit answers.

Comment: I added my findings to the answer.

Comment: You added them to the *question* but that is just as good: comments *can* disappear but the question/answer combo contains all the relevant information  and so has a better chance of being useful to others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: does libnotify have equivalent in macOS?